# How do I get the keys from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, react-context

I'm having difficulty working with an object returned by a GraphQl call to dynamoDB. I've given each nested object a number for a key. It's the number I'm trying to use to create the array of keys, using Object.keys()

```js
const groupsContext = {"01":{"Status":"Active","Name":"Group 1"},"02":{"Status":"Active","Name":"Group 2"}}

let groupKeys = Object.keys(groupsContext)
console.log(groupKeys)
```

This is the console output:

```
Array(2897) [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", … ]
```

I've tried this on codepen and it works so I'm not sure what's different. The only thing I can think of is that I'm missing something between creating the application context and trying to create the keys from the context.

Here is the code I use to create the context:

//Context file

```
import { useContext, createContext } from "react";

export const GroupsContext = createContext(null);

export function useGroupsContext() {
  return useContext(GroupsContext);
}
```

//App

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GroupsContext } from "./libs/context/groupsLib";

function App() {
  const [groupsContext, setGroupsContext] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    let apiGroups
    try {
      apiGroups = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getQuery, { PK: "Status", SK: "Test" }));
      setGroupsContext(apiGroups.data.getQuery.FullGroups)
      
    } catch (e) {
      if (e !== "Error") {
        onError(e);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <GroupsContext.Provider value={{ groupsContext, setGroupsContext }}>
          <Routing />
        </GroupsContext.Provider>
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default App;
```

//getGroups

```
import { useGroupsContext } from "../../libs/context/groupsLib";

export default function ActiveGroups() {
  const { groupsContext } = useGroupsContext()


let groupKeys = Object.keys(groupsContext)
console.log(groupKeys)
```

As you can see the array should only have a length of two. How can I create the array to show just the number keys?

Comment: my guess is your keys are not strings. What is `console.log(JSON.stringify(apiGroups.data.getQuery.FullGroups))`

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with the current output and what do you mean by 'correctly' in your question, please?

Comment: I changed your first code to a runnable snippet, and you can clearly see the output is not what you said it is - so it's unclear what your question is.

Comment: If you read the question, that's my point. The array in the console log does not match what it should be, i.e. what you've now shown after the runnable snippet.

Comment: This is the result of console.log(JSON.stringify(apiGroups.data.getQuery.FullGroups))      "{\"01\":{\"Status\":\"Active\",\"Name\":\"Group 1\"},\"02\":{\"Status\":\"Active\",\"Name\":\"Group 2\"}}"

Comment: Can you confirm that your object properties are enumerable? eg, does using `console.log(apiGroups.data.getQuery.FullGroups.propertyIsEnumerable("01"))`  log `true`?

Comment: console.log(apiGroups.data.getQuery.FullGroups.propertyIsEnumerable("01"))  returns false

Comment: hm, since it is giving `false` that either means `01` isn't a valid property to check (but from your output, it seems like it should be), or your keys aren't enumerable (which means `Object.keys()` won't return them), maybe try using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(apiGroups.data.getQuery.FullGroups)` instead? This will get the non-enumerable keys also (but won't get the inherited ones like Object.keys() does)

Comment: Thanks. Tried:

let groupKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(groupsContext)
console.log(groupKeys)

which just gives the same array result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nick P for his thoughts on enumerable properties. I've amended the code to this:

```
let groupKeys = []
  for (const key in groupsContext) {
    groupKeys.push(`${key}`);
  }
  console.log(groupKeys)
```